# forkJoin get request value

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

I am trying to call multiple APIs using forkJoin. I believe the order in which the results will be return can be random. Is it possible to know which result belongs to which request?

**Existing code:**

```
interface Data {
  id: number, 
  input1: number,
  input2: number,
  sum?: number
}

arrayOfData : Data[] = [{id:1, input1: 5, input2: 3}, {id:2, input1: 2, input2: 4}, {id:3, input1: 1, input2: 4}];

let requests: Observable<Data>[] = [];

calculateSum(d:Data) : Observable<Data>{
     return this.callAPI(d);
}

let arrayOfData.forEach(d => {
  requests.push(this.calculateSum(d));
});

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(results => {
   // results : [{sum: 6}, {sum: 8}, {sum: 5}]
   // result only has sum, it does not include id. 
   // how can I assign this back to the correct array item of Data?
 
});
```

Should I use another operator instead of forkJoin?

Comment: forkJoin *returns an Observable that emits either an array of values in the exact same order as the passed array* https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L50

Comment: requests are in the same order that the results are. no matter when API response is came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API doesn't return the id with the response, you have to keep track of it yourself. `forkJoin` is ordered, so this is quite easy to manage with the [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator.

Try this:

```js
interface Data {
  id: number, 
  input1: number,
  input2: number,
  sum?: number
}

arrayOfData: Data[] = [{id:1, input1: 5, input2: 3}, {id:2, input1: 2, input2: 4}, {id:3, input1: 1, input2: 4}];

calculateSum(d:Data) : Observable<Data>{
     return this.callAPI(d);
}

let requests: Observable<Data>[] = arrayOfData.map(d => this.calculateSum(d))

forkJoin(requests)
.pipe(
    map(results => results.map((r, i) => ({ ...r, id: arrayOfData[i].id })))
)
.subscribe(results => {
   // results : [{id: 1, sum: 6}, {id: 2, sum: 8}, {id: 3, sum: 5}]
});
```